# Import database into MyPhpAdmin

Tags: mysql, import, phpmyadmin

I'm kind of a beginner and I am trying to import a database into myphpadmin for a new website.

The database is a 38GB sql file, which makes things a little bit harder.

Here is what I tried.

1. My website host told me to use FTP to import the sql file into the website. It's a wordpress website, I used filezilla to transfer the file to the public_html folder. But now I have no idea what to do with it so...
   [image]
2. I tried to use the myphpadmin import function but it only takes files up to 512MB.
3. Then I tried to use SSH but it is probably blocked by my host.
   [image: I always get this error (it means access denied for user...]

(it says access denied for user...)
I'm running out of ideas and my host is just running in circles telling me they activated SSH and I have to try again in 30min then they say bye and it doesn't work so I contact them again etc...

I'm running out of ideas !

Thank you for reading

Comment: Phpmyadmin is not suitable for importing a 38GB file. End of story. You need a different mysql client. Even cli will do.

Comment: "giga" and "mega" are not a unit of size.

Comment: Can you use [MySQL Workbench](https://www.mysql.com/products/workbench/) instead?

Answer (score -1):

First, there are also other Graphical Interfaces to Databases. [This Article introduces some of them](https://www.eversql.com/top-7-mysql-gui-tools-for-windows/).

Secondly:

- Find `config.inc.php` from phpmyadmin
- add this, or similar, if the config file has slightly different options... and adapt it to the remote db

```
$i++;
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['host'] = 'DATABASE_HOST:PORT';//set the database hostname.
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['user'] = 'DATABASE_USER';// set the remote database user
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['password'] = 'DATABASE_PASSWORD';// database password
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['auth_type'] = 'config';
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I think I have no choice to use myphpadmin since it's the only one my host is providing. I'm not sure where I can find the config.inc.php file since the server is on their side